# How to bind name to in drop down list using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

JSON data is retrieved as shown:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jon",
    "creator_id": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-26T18:58:12.62",
    "change_date": "2015-10-27T18 
    :58:12.62",
    "changer_id": 1,
    "deleted": null
},
{
    "id": 43,
    "name": "sam",
    "creator_id": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-27T16
    :36:25.45",
    "change_date": null,
    "changer_id": null,
    "deleted": null
},
{
    "id": 45,
    "name": "Alex",
    "creator_id": 0,
    "date": "2015-10-27T17:25:04.903",
    "change_date": null,
    "changer_id": null,
    "deleted": null
}
```

I want to bind names in drop down list using JQuery, How to do that?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="sel_group" name="groups" class="bs-select form-control input-medium">
        <option value="">Select Group....</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to parse json before use. But you can append like this:

```
$.each(json_data, function(index, obj){ // assuming json_data variable having json
    $("#sel_group").append("<option value='"+obj.id+"'>"+obj.name+"</option>")
})
```

Comment: what index, object, obj.id+ do exactly ?

Comment: Didn't understand, can you explain?

Comment: I mean, why did you use index and obj `(index, obj)`, and what `id+` does ?

Comment: That is system of [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) first parameter should be index second should be object. And if you try to `console.log(obj.id)` it will print id of each object. `+` is just used for separator with string.